# Moped: How to adduser to a mongo database

Tags: ruby, mongodb, moped

Is there a way to add user to a database from Moped. I dont see any equivalent command to mongo console

```
db.addUser(user, pass, [roles])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from MongoDB 3.0 U have to use createUser, not addUser. 
The syntax is:

```
db.createUser(
    {
      user: "username",
      pwd: "12345678",
      roles: [
         { role: "read", db: "reporting" },
         { role: "read", db: "products" },
         { role: "read", db: "sales" },
         { role: "readWrite", db: "accounts" }
      ]
    }
)
```

To add root admin use the following:

```
db.createUser({ user: "admin", pwd: "adminpwd", roles: [ "root" ]})
```

look at here:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-user-to-database/

Answer (score 2):

Its something like that:

```
db.collection.insert( { user: "username", password: 'password', roles: ['role1','role2'] )
```